# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when executin SQL with SET in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I am creating set, to prevent duplicates while I am deleting old folders on server depending on status in column of table. But when I try to run this script

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql="SELECT id, name, state FROM domain WHERE state='2'"
cursor.execute(sql)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print("Total number of records for deleting is: ", cursor.rowcount)

deleted = set(cursor.execute("select distinct name from domain where state = 2"))
active = set(cursor.execute("select distinct name from domain where state != 2"))

to_delete = deleted - active

print('Printing each domain record', "\n")
for row in records:

    print("id = ", row["id"], )
    print("name = ", row["name"])
    print("state  = ", row["state"], "\n")

    id = row["id"]
    name = row["name"]
    state = row["state"]

    if to_delete == 2:
        try:
            if os.path.exists('/data/sa/' + name):
                print('found records for deleting: ' + name, "\n")
                print("Total number of records for deleting is: ", cursor.rowcount)
                input("Press Enter to continue...")
                shutil.rmtree('/data/sa/' + name)
                print('records deleted')            
            else:
                print('no Directory found')
        #    pass
        except Exception as error:
            print("Directory already deleted or never existed")
    else:
        print('no records for deleting found')
        print('domain', name)
        print('hast state', state, "\n")

quit()
connection.close()
```

I've to this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mazani_old_zaznamu2.py", line 21, in <module>
    deleted = set(cursor.execute("select distinct name from domain where state = 2"))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I asume that's because there is alot of domain rows, so I have to sort them somehow make iterable, but I dont know how is that possible.

Comment: What SQL library is that? Please add a tag.

Comment: sorry, done. It is pymysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute method doesn't return the rows itself, just [the number of affected rows](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html).

To get the results, try:

```
cursor.execute("select distinct name from domain where state = 2")
deleted = set(d['name'] for d in cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: Well, I've fot this error now

``    deleted = set(cursor.fetchall())
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' ``

Comment: Edited the answer. I don't have a MySQL db set up myself unfortunately.

Comment: This actually works perfectly. Can I ask for explanation what is there the "d" for in d['name']

Comment: Great! Each d corresponds to a row. Naming it `row` would probably be better. And a row is a dict with the columns as keys and the entry in that row as the value.